# FactoryGirl error : rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I cannot run rpsec after merging my code from Github.

I keep getting FactoryGirl error :
`uninitialized constant ControllerMacros::FactoryGirl`
`` 1) Question has a valid factory

      Failure/Error: expect(FactoryGirl.build(:question)).to be_valid

     NameError:

       uninitialized constant FactoryGirl

     # ./spec/models/question_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in ' ``

Please help.

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` after merging?

Comment: yeah! Tried that too but din't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that FactoryGirl may be missing some definitions. [Try declaring the following](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#using-without-bundler) in your `spec_helper`:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
require 'factory_girl'
FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much :)
I din't have <code>FactoryGirl.find_definitions</code> in my spec_helper.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a Rails project, you can avoid finding definitions manually by using [factory_girl_rails](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails), which will automatically load your definitions for you.